# How to copy Test data file to jmeter slave machines

Tags: jmeter

I'm Using JMeter project to execute the performance test using jenkin. Although right now will be uploading the test data files to remote machines manually. Is there any way to configure sending data files to remote machines using the pom file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this via *pom.file* as [JMeter Maven plugin doesn't support this yet](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/35)

However if you will be running [JMeter from command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) you can pass the properties in form `key=value` or even the *.properties* file via [`-G` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -n -R localhost -Gfoo=bar -t test.jmx
```

or

```
jmeter -n -R localhost -Gglobal.properties
```

and these properties will be propagated to all remote slaves

[image]